# Cypress - Adding handelExpection code but still can't catch the app exceptions

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test this site https://store.google.com/regionpicker and when I select a region (US) for example and get redirected to this url: https://store.google.com/us/?hl=en-US&regionRedirect=true I get an app error in the console, and cypress fails to continue

I added this code to handle exceptions before the test starts, but it doesn't catch it:

```
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
          return false
        })
```

full code:

```
describe('Purchase a device from Google Store', () => {

const LOCATORS = {
    devicesMenu: '[id="desktop-products"]',
    headerContainer: '.header-container',
    regionTitle: '.region-title',
    dialog: '[role="dialog"]',
    button: '[role="button"]',
}

before(() => {
    cy.visit('/')
})

beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
        return false
    })
})

it('Purchase device', () => {
    let region = 'United States'
    let urlToVerify = 'us/?hl=en-US&regionRedirect=true'

    cy.contains(LOCATORS.regionTitle, region)
    .click().then(() => {
        cy.get(LOCATORS.dialog).within(() => {
        cy.contains('Continue')
            .click({ force: true }).then(() => {
                cy.url()
                .should('include', urlToVerify)
            })
    })
    })
})
```

})

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can test the URL in an event handler for the `url:changed` event.

The basic problem seems to be that it's not possible to take Cypress to `https://store.google.com`, the browser ends up with URL `about:blank`.

But by adding a listener to `url:changed` you can at least verify that the correct URL was attempted.

```js
it('redirects after region select', () => {

  const region = 'United States'
  const urlToVerify = 'us/?hl=en-US&regionRedirect=true'

  cy.on('url:changed', (url) => {
    expect(url).to.include(urlToVerify)   // use chai to assert
  })

  cy.contains(LOCATORS.regionTitle, region).click()
  cy.get(LOCATORS.dialog).within(() => {
    cy.contains('Continue').click({ force: true })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Steve, but it didn't help. I can see that the exception was indeed caught but this happens after being redirected to the screen and after interacting with its elements. Updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: Added to the question, please check.

base url is https://store.google.com/regionpicker

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. 
I also have Cypress.on(...) in support/index.js as a global solution but doesn't help also

Comment: Thank you Steve, but verifying the url was just an example to simplify the question. I need to do many validations on the screen after the url changes. 
Do you think that this is a limitation for cypress that it can't handle all app exceptions?

Comment: The first exception "Cannot read property name of null" is just the Cypress runner saying it's unable to show the shapshot, nothing to do with the test. Try visiting shop.google, you will see you cannot, something on the page prevents it.

Comment: I see. Yes there is something that prevents the page from loading, it loads a blank page. 
I don't think anything further can be done here.